# openTBS/PHP - How do I create a stacked bar chart?

Tags: php, opentbs

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart as shown below embedded on a slide of a PowerPoint template.  When I run my script below I am getting an error.

> TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: (ChartChangeSeries) 'chart3' :
>   unable to found series 'Series 3' in the chart 'chart3'. The process
>   is ending, unless you set NoErr property to true.

As far as I can see my series are clearly defined along with each of the two labels for the x axis.

**Where am I going wrong and how can I resolve this error?**

[image: Table Definition in Template]

[image: Stacked Bar Chart Sample Image]

```
$ecdClosureStatus = getClosureChartData('ECD');
    $ChartNameOrNum = 'chart3'; // Title of the shape that embeds the chart
    $ChartRef = 'chart3'; // Title of the shape that embeds the chart
    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 1';
    $NewLegend = "Closed On Time";
    $NewValues =    array(


(int)$ecdClosureStatus['ClosedOnTime'],
                                    0
                                );
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

$SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 2';
$NewLegend =    'Closed 1-30 Days Late';
$NewValues =    array(
                                    0,
                                    (int)$ecdClosureStatus['OneToThirtyDaysLate']
                                );
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

$SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 3';
$NewLegend =        'Closed 31-60 Days Late';
$NewValues =    array(
                                    0,
                                    (int)$ecdClosureStatus['ThirtyOneToSixtyDaysLate']
                                );
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

$SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 4';
$NewLegend =    'Closed 61-90 Days Late';
$NewValues =        array(
                                    0,
                                    (int)$ecdClosureStatus['SixtyOneToNinetyDaysLate']
                                );
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

$SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 5';
$NewLegend = 'Closed >90 Days Late';
$NewValues =    array(
                                    0,
                                    (int)$ecdClosureStatus['ClosedMoreThanNinetyDaysLate']
                                );
$TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my $NewValues array for each of the series to  be an array of two elements, with the first element being the x axis values and the second element being the y axis value.  The x axis value was an array of two values ("Closed On Time", "Closed Late"), and the y axis was an array of two elements (one element being zero and the other being the value for that x value (either closed on time or closed late)

**Output Graph**

[image: Output Stacked Bar Chart]

**Example**

```
 $NewValues =   array(array('Closed On Time', 'Closed Late'), array(
                                        (int)$ecdClosureStatus['ClosedOnTime'],
                                        0
                                    ));
```

**Solution Code**

```
$ecdClosureStatus = getClosureChartData('ECD');
    $ChartNameOrNum = 'chart3'; // Title of the shape that embeds the chart
    $ChartRef = 'chart3'; // Title of the shape that embeds the chart
    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 1';
    $NewLegend = "Closed On Time";
    $NewValues =    array(array('Closed On Time', 'Closed Late'), array(
                                        (int)$ecdClosureStatus['ClosedOnTime'],
                                        0
                                    ));
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 2';
    $NewLegend =    '1-30 Days Late';
    $NewValues =        array(array('Closed On Time', 'Closed Late'), array(
                                        0,
                                        (int)$ecdClosureStatus['OneToThirtyDaysLate']
                                    ));
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 3';
    $NewLegend =        ' 31-60 Days Late';
    $NewValues =        array(array('Closed On Time', 'Closed Late'), array(
                                        0,
                                        (int)$ecdClosureStatus['ThirtyOneToSixtyDaysLate']
                                    ));
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 4';
    $NewLegend =    '61-90 Days Late';
    $NewValues =            array(array('Closed On Time', 'Closed Late'), array(
                                        0,
                                        (int)$ecdClosureStatus['SixtyOneToNinetyDaysLate']
                                    ));
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);

    $SeriesNameOrNum = 'Series 5';
    $NewLegend = ' >90 Days Late';
    $NewValues =        array(array('Closed On Time', 'Closed Late'), array(
                                        0,
                                        (int)$ecdClosureStatus['MoreThanNinetyDaysLate']
                                    ));
    $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART, $ChartNameOrNum, $SeriesNameOrNum, $NewValues, $NewLegend);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems ok.The problem probably comes from the the series #3 which may not be named internally as you expect. Double check the name in the Spreadsheet viewer, there must be no spaces at the end. You can also try with the button « Modify data in Ms Excel ».

Nevertheless you can use the new OpenTBS command that return the data of a chart. It's avaibale in [OpenTBS beta version 1.9.5](https://github.com/Skrol29/opentbs) but it is stable.

Command:

```
$data = $TBS->PlugIn(OPENTBS_CHART_INFO, 'chart3');   
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  In my $ecdClosureStatus array I found that I had an incorrect name for one of my keys  After changing the array key name I modified my code and got the result.  I will post the code for the solution.